# Como garantir que um serviço esteja sempre em execução no CentOS?

Tags: python, linux, django, centos

Criei um script de inicialização para meu aplicativo no CentOS, com isso, eu posso utilizar os comandos abaixo para inicializar/interromper o aplicativo:

```
service django_app start
service django_app stop
```

Como faço para garantir que este serviço esteja sempre em execução?

Por exemplo, se houver algum erro no aplicativo e o serviço for finalizado, existem alguma forma de reiniciar o serviço automaticamente no CentOS?

Comment: Uma solução é criar um cronjob que rode a cada X minutos, e que rode um script que faça a verificação e reinicialização se for necessária.

Comment: Um comando do tipo `ps aux | grep "django_app"` pode ajudar a verificar se o aplicativo está entre os processos em execução.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

procure o monit, um orquestrador simples e funcional:

exemplo de config:

```
check process meuapp with pidfile /var/vcqescolhe/app.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/app  start" uid 500 gid 499
stop program = "/etc/init.d/app stop" uid 500 gid 499
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 8080 then restart
if failed host localhost port 8080
    protocol HTTP request "/meuapp/beheappy/smileinsignificante.jpg" with timeout     10 seconds then restart
```

esse monitor inclusive pode mandar e-mails... fica mais rápido que um nagios ou zabbix

Comment: esqueci o site dele.. http://mmonit.com/monit/

Answer (score 2):

Um jeito bem mais simples do que o monit, como comentado pelo J. Bruni na sua pergunta, é fazer um script.

vi /xyz/django_app_verify.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! "$(pidof django_app)" ] 
then
  /xyz/comandoParaIniciarSeu_django_app &
fi
```

Depois acrescentar no crontab

```
* * * * * /xyz/django_app_verify.sh > /dev/null
```

Assim ele é executado a todo minuto. Essa solução é mais frequente do que parece.

Answer (score 1):

Outra alternativa é o Supervisor!

```
pip install supervisor
```

Aí você cria um arquivo de configuração com os programas que serão monitorados. Um exemplo mínimo seria:

```
[program:foo]
command=/bin/cat
```

O tutorial oficial fica [nessa página](http://supervisord.org/index.html).